# Aspirin - does it inhibit enzyme of thromboxane?

Tags: pharmacology, enzymes, aspirin

This is a diagram a friend showed me about the drug aspirin, where we were arguing which enzyme it prevents. 
[image]

Aspirin is known to inhibit the production of prostaglandins. However, it also serves fit as a purpose to inhibit production of thromboxane.

My question is, does the drug inhibit enzyme a to prevent the production of both thromboxane and prostaglandins, or only enzyme B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aspirin and some other [NSAIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsteroidal_anti-inflammatory_drug) inhibit [cyclooxygenase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclooxygenase) which is the first enzyme in the prostaglandin/thromboxane biosynthesis pathway if you consider first substance is [arachidonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachidonic_acid) (a fatty acid). Generally, arachidonic acid is present in the form of a phospholipid, and if you consider that in the pathway, substance-Y is arachidonic acid and enzyme-A is cyclooxygenase.

---

> [image]
>   **From:** Heckmann, Lars-Henrik, et al. "[Outlining eicosanoid biosynthesis in the crustacean Daphnia.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1742-9994-5-11)" *Front. Zool* 5.11 (2008).